# Can't Get .NET XPathNavigator to work

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xpathnavigator

I am having problems with XPathNavigator. I have a document with a bunch of "topic" elements w/o namespace in a stream.

I am using (expression dumbed down to bare minimum, first I thought my expressions were wrong):

```
XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument( stream );
XPathNavigator xml = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iter = xml.Select( "//topic" );
```

This doesn't work. I can select `*/*/*` or something similar and get my "topic" elements alright.
I tried running my expressions in online tester and other languages and they work.

Question: what's wrong? I have lingering suspicion that it has to do with accursed NamespaceManager object, which causes me incredible pain every time I parse document with namespaces, but this time the elements I am seeking don't have an explicit namespace!
I added:

```
XmlNamespaceManager s = new XmlNamespaceManager( xml.NameTable );
```

and pass that as 2nd argument to Select - to no avail. How am I supposed to add "" namespace to this thing/use it correctly?

Or, better yet, is there way to use XPath in .NET without using this horrible abomination of the class, like in other languages? If I want namespaces, I can write them in the expression...

Update:
I figured out a workaround- copy/paste default xmlns from root node, and then use that namespace:

```
thisIsRetarded.AddNamespace( "x", "urn:xmind:xmap:xmlns:content:2.0" );
XPathNodeIterator projectIter = projectTree.Select( "//x:topic", thisIsRetarded );
```

however, neither I am supposed to know the default URI, nor do I like to pollute my expressions with unnecessary x:-s. So I only need answer to 2nd part of the question now.

Comment: You _are_ supposed to know the namespaces. Two elements with the same name are _different_ if they are in different namespaces.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that naming a variable `thisIsRetarded` reveals just the wrong attitude for a programmer. Things are not retarded just because you fail to make sense of them.

Comment: But it *is* rather stupid if the element does not have a prefix in your xml document and you have to create some artificial construct in your xpath api to select it.

Comment: Ha ha:  "thisIsRetarded.AddNamespace..."  +1

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("sample", "...");
doc.Load(stream);

XmlNode topic = doc.SelectSingleNode("/sample:topic", nsmgr);

// If you don't have any namespaces....
XmlNode topic2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("/topic");
```

Comment: The important part is - if you have namespaces, then you need to reference them in your XPATH expressions!

Answer (score 0):

Check this StackOverflow answer to the same problem with the explanation between the default namespace and no namespace:
[Xml-SelectNodes with default-namespace via XmlNamespaceManager not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271689/xml-selectnodes-with-default-namespace-via-xmlnamespacemanager-not-working-as-ex/4271875#4271875)

And an even better explanation by Microsoft on how to use the default namespace:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xpath-queries-and-namespaces