# How to Select an XML Node with a Namespace in LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have an xml document in the below format.

```
<Abc xmlns="http://qusetons.com/Cdc/AbcSchema.xsd">
  <xxx>False</xxx>
  <yyy>True</yyy>
  <sss>Pd</sss>
</Abc>
```

I am using XDocument class to parse this document

```
 var doc= XDocument.Load(fullfilepath);
```

now the below code to get the value of   node is not working. wat should i do to get this code?

```
doc.XPathSelectElement("/Abc/xxx").value
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(data);  
var names = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
names.AddNamespace("emtpy", "http://qusetons.com/Cdc/AbcSchema.xsd");
Console.WriteLine(doc.XPathSelectElement("/emtpy:Abc/emtpy:xxx", names).Value);
```

Comment: Really this is the format i ma expecting . But while executing i am getting the below error   "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed."

Comment: Very fine it is working good. the issue is i havent added names as an argument. One more is how can i avoid this "/empty" with a blank string

Comment: This could help you to find out answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271689/xml-selectnodes-with-default-namespace-via-xmlnamespacemanager-not-working-as-ex)

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.Elements(XName.Get("xxx"));
```