# Document.SelectNodes returning zero nodes. Is there anything wrong in my xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, domparser

I have following xml. But, when I am loading it and selecting node I am getting 0 nodes. Is there anything wrong with my xml?

**Code to load xml :**

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(strOfferListing);
 XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                        mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd");
                        mgr.AddNamespace("root", "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01");
    var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//GetMatchingProductResponse");
```

**This is my xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GetMatchingProductResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"><GetMatchingProductResult ASIN="0470265957" status="Success"><Product><Identifiers><MarketplaceASIN><MarketplaceId>XXXXXXXXXX</MarketplaceId><ASIN>0470265957</ASIN></MarketplaceASIN></Identifiers><AttributeSets><ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd"><ns2:Author>Milton H. Erickson</ns2:Author><ns2:Author>Ernest L. Rossi</ns2:Author><ns2:Binding>Hardcover</ns2:Binding><ns2:Edition>1st</ns2:Edition><ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>true</ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn><ns2:Label>Irvington Publishers</ns2:Label><ns2:Languages><ns2:Language><ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name><ns2:Type>Published</ns2:Type></ns2:Language><ns2:Language><ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name><ns2:Type>Original Language</ns2:Type></ns2:Language><ns2:Language><ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name><ns2:Type>Unknown</ns2:Type></ns2:Language></ns2:Languages><ns2:ListPrice><ns2:Amount>211.86</ns2:Amount><ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode></ns2:ListPrice><ns2:Manufacturer>Irvington Publishers</ns2:Manufacturer><ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems><ns2:NumberOfPages>512</ns2:NumberOfPages><ns2:PackageDimensions><ns2:Height Units="inches">1.70</ns2:Height><ns2:Length Units="inches">9.40</ns2:Length><ns2:Width Units="inches">6.30</ns2:Width><ns2:Weight Units="pounds">1.85</ns2:Weight></ns2:PackageDimensions><ns2:ProductGroup>Book</ns2:ProductGroup><ns2:ProductTypeName>ABIS_BOOK</ns2:ProductTypeName><ns2:PublicationDate>1979-10-01</ns2:PublicationDate><ns2:Publisher>Irvington Publishers</ns2:Publisher><ns2:SmallImage><ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51geup2R-DL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL><ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height><ns2:Width Units="pixels">56</ns2:Width></ns2:SmallImage><ns2:Studio>Irvington Publishers</ns2:Studio><ns2:Title>Hypnotherapy: An Exploratory Casebook</ns2:Title></ns2:ItemAttributes></AttributeSets><Relationships /><SalesRankings><SalesRank><ProductCategoryId>book_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId><Rank>562887</Rank></SalesRank><SalesRank><ProductCategoryId>3558816011</ProductCategoryId><Rank>63</Rank></SalesRank><SalesRank><ProductCategoryId>173514</ProductCategoryId><Rank>38091</Rank></SalesRank></SalesRankings></Product></GetMatchingProductResult></GetMatchingProductResponse>
```

Comment: The same xml which is below mentioned

Comment: You're not including the namespace of the node. Unqualified names will only match the empty namespace. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271875/4137916).

Comment: I tried adding namespace also. Please look at the edited code. It was of no help.

Comment: You query *still does not include a namespace*. Use `//root:GetMatchingProductResponse`.