# How to select Nodes in XML correctly?

Tags: c#, xml

i have following XML-File

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<server xmlns="exampleServer">  
    <system-properties>
        <property name="prop0" value="null"/>
        <property name="prop1" value="true"/>
        <property name="prop2" value="false"/>
    </system-properties>    
</server>
```

and this.Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;            
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//system-properties/property");
```

But nodeList.Count are always 0.
I have tried

```
root.SelectNodes("/system-properties/property");
root.SelectNodes("system-properties/property");
root.SelectNodes("//property");
```

..a.s.o.   but nothing works.
Evaluation of the var's show the Childnodes but there are not selected.

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a namespace in your XML: `<server xmlns="exampleServer">`. When using XPath, it's assumed that elements have no namespace if you don't add a prefix in your path. See [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271875/3034273).

In your situation you need to use an [XmlNamespaceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager?view=net-6.0)  with your XPath and specify the namespace of the elements you are searching for:

```
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("es", "exampleServer");
        
var properties = root.SelectNodes("//es:system-properties/es:property", nsMgr);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZDiTtb) for a test run.

Comment: Thanx, that saves my day:-)
but now i get errors when i try to create a new property with those 2 attributes..
What is the best way to add a new 'property' line?

Comment: @Guest I'm not sure what that error is, but it sounds like a different problem. If you post a new question with details about it we can take a look.